# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "MY AWS DATABASE" while creating a webapp (POSTGRES)

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, jdbc

I am getting a stacktrace. note that my AWSdb-URL is a fake url for this post.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "MyAWSDB-URL?currentSchema=mySchema"
```

This is my connection Factory(JDBC)

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory(1);
    
    public static ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
        return cf;
    }
    

    private Connection[] conn;
    
    
    private ConnectionFactory(int numberOfConnections) {
        
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        String url = System.getenv("DB_URL");
        
        String user = System.getenv("DB_USER");
        String password = System.getenv("DB_PASS");
        

        

        try {
            this.conn = new Connection[numberOfConnections];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.conn.length; i++) {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                this.conn[i] = conn;
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return this.conn[0];
    };
    
    public void releaseConnection(Connection conn) {
        //do nothing - release conn after use if in multiple threads
    };
```

And this is the DAO(Data access object) that uses my connection factory

```
public class EmployeeDAO {
    private ConnectionFactory cf = ConnectionFactory.getConnectionFactory();
    

    
    
    
//  -----------------------------------------------------------LOGIN AND GET EMPLOYEE CREDENTIALS--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public User login(String username, String pass) {
        Connection conn = this.cf.getConnection();
        User loginCredentials = null;
        
        
            try {
                String sql = "select * from \"user\" u \r\n"
                        + "where username = "+username+" and pass = "+pass;
                
                Statement s = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet res = s.executeQuery(sql);
                
                while(res.next()) {
                    loginCredentials = new User(res.getInt("user_id"),res.getString("fname"), res.getString("lname"), res.getString("username"), res.getString("pass"), res.getString("email"));
                }
                
                System.out.println(loginCredentials.toString());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    

            return loginCredentials;


    }
    
}
```

This is a maven project and i have my dependency at pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.18</version>
</dependency>
```

I have my ENV variables set up properly. IDK what i'm doing wrong. Please lead me on the right direction.
My WEB-INF -> lib has nothing on it

Comment: What's the value of `DB_URL`?

Comment: My amazon database url. I could post it here but I've used the same database env var on another project and it worked fine

Comment: If you're sure. But when I run `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("\"MyAWSDB-URL?currentSchema=mySchema\""); I get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "MyAWSDB-URL?currentSchema=mySchema"` which seems very similar, and uses an invalid JDBC URL.

Comment: Cause that is not the actual url. I modified it for this post since i was thinking that the url is not the problem because the actual url I'm using works on another project

Comment: Is the error message the real error message?

Comment: I could try and post the actual url in a moment.thank you for looking into this

Comment: Thats the actual error message but again i removed the full url name

Comment: Doing that without mentioning it makes it difficult to help.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will modify my post. Again I'm sorry and i appreciate it

Comment: You have anonymized your URL too much. Please make sure that the actual structure of the URL is preserved (eg the protocol prefix, position of hostname and port, etc). An error like this is usually caused by either the driver not being present, the driver not having been registered, or you using an incorrect URL. BTW: Why are you trying to create a poor man's `DataSource`? It would be better to use a standard data source of a connection pool like HikariCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you passed to `DriverManager.getConnection` is not a valid JDBC URL.

The Url should looks like the following:

```
jdbc:postgresql://postgresql-instance1.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/myDatabase
```

Of course, this is only an example.

You need to provide the prefix `jdbc:postgresql://` and then the rest of the connection string. You can find the exact value in the detail page of your database in the Amazon RDS console.

Please, consider review the point 4 in the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-connect-postgresql-db/?nc1=h_ls) related on how to connect to a PostgreSQL DB in Amazon RDS.

Comment: Thank you! this led me to the right answer i appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome @Ruvin. I am happy to know that the answer was helpful. Thank you very much